# jQuery - Targeting specific ID's

Tags: jquery

I have the following code:

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
$("input:checkbox").click(function(){
    var group = "input:checkbox[name='"+$(this).attr("name")+"']";
    $(group).attr("checked",false);
    $(this).attr("checked",true);
});
});
</script>
```

How do i get it to target a specific  ID rather than every checkbox on the page?

i.e if the group of checkboxes im trying to target is #thisgroup

Cheers,

Comment: Are you referring to the `group` selector?

Comment: I think so, im not really sure how to change this statement to target only 1 set of checkboxes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would use .removeAttr("checked") instead of setting the checked attribute to false. Something like

```
    $(function() {
        $("input:checkbox").change(function() {
            var checkname = $(this).attr("name");
            $("input:checkbox[name='" + checkname + "']").removeAttr("checked");
            this.checked = true;
        });
    });
```

You can see a [**working demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/mvWhS/1/)

If you want to target checkboxes inside a specific container then you can set that also, like

```
$("#checkboxcontainer input:checkbox").change(function(){
    // your code goes here
});
```

Comment: Can i target that statement to a specific group of checkboxes? ... say #thisgroup ?

Answer (score 2):

You can actually rewrite this to something simpler:

```
$(this).attr('checked', true).siblings().attr('checked', false);
```

This is assuming that the checkboxes all share a single parent.

Answer (score 1):

You can use this selector:

```
$('#thisgroup :checkbox')....
```

where `thisgroup` is the group/container of your check boxes.

Comment: I have changed all the instaces, but it doesnt seem to be working ... what about the group line which is var group = "input:checkbox[name='"+$(this).attr("name")+"']";
should i change that to var group = "#thisgroup :checkbox[name='"+$(this).attr("name")+"']";